# How can I test an ad?

Tags: android, admob

I'd like to test some `adView` in my app. Thus, I declared the View as following:

```
        <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="12345"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        />
```

I reference it in my Fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container,
            false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_frag_list);
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getActivity()
            .getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
    AdRequest adReq = new AdRequest();
    adReq.addTestDevice(deviceid);
    AdView adview = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adview.loadAd(adReq);

            ................................ //some code

    return rootView;
}
```

The `adView` stays blank and I get the `onFailedToReceiveAd` error. I guess this is because I do not have a valid AdUnitId. How can I get it working for test purposes?

Comment: Just get an ad unit id by registering your app, it should work then.

Comment: well the app is in early development stage, I have about 30% of work done, for sure it's not published anywhere. Can't I test ads at this point?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, you can set up your app even it's still in development stages and not published, yet (unless the new AdMob interface changed the rules by now). Just make sure to use AdMob in debug mode. If you want to see it in production mode make sure not to click any ads :-)

Comment: Check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25857793/1207281. It will make show test ad on any device

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.setTesting(true);
```

but since it is deprecated you should use this method:

```
adRequest.setTestDevices(Set<String> testDevices)
```

testDevices variable contains ids of devices on which you are going to test.

Comment: Set<String> devs = new HashSet<String>();
  devs.add(tm.getDeviceId());  still getting the error: 08-13 20:13:32.763: I/Ads(9187): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL. 
08-13 20:13:32.763: I/Ads(9187): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)

Comment: 60000ms? the message appears immediately after app's launch, permission INTERNET is present

Comment: Have you tried looking in your log for device id? Check this line in logcat: To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("7AFF7E88C3968AA19FE6AC26C435B0CA");

Comment: You need android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission too

Comment: I have the permission you mentioned. The ID seems to be just a large number, is something wrong with that?

Comment: It`s not just a large number. Every device has a unique id. It is not some random number :)

Comment: I'm logging the result of tm.getDeviceId() and it's always the same, thought it only contain digits

Comment: try adding this in your layout: googleads:loadOnCreate="true" then you do not need that java code, it will automaticly load ad. Not sure if you can set testing attr from layout, you need to check that

Comment: I just saw that you are calling this from onCreateView. Try calling it from onCreate or onStart method...